# List with two different entities based on segment selection

Tags: list, foreach, entity, swiftui

I don't know if it's possible. I would like that depending on what is selected in the segments the list changes Entity. Similar to what Apple does in its examples with Landmarks but instead of favorites ....

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        VStack {
                            Picker(selection: self.$userData.tipoSeleccionado,
                                   label: Text("....?")) {
                                ForEach(0..<self.Tipo.count) { index in
                                    Text(self.Tipo[index]).tag(index)
                                }
                            }   .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        }
                        if self.containedViewType == .tipo1 {
                            ForEach(self.listadoTipo1, id: \.self) { elemento in
                                NavigationLink(destination: Tipo1Detail(elementoSeleccionado: elemento)) {
                                    Tipo1Row(tipo: elemento)
                                }   .navigationBarTitle("Busqueda")
                                    .navigationBarHidden(false)
                            }   .onDelete(perform: self.removeTipo1)
                        }
                        if self.containedViewType == .tipo2 {
                            ForEach(self.listadoTipo2, id: \.self) { elemento in
                                NavigationLink(destination: Tipo2Detail(elementoSeleccionado: elemento)) {
                                    Tipo2Row(tipo: elemento)
                                }   .navigationBarTitle("Busqueda")
                                    .navigationBarHidden(false)
                             }   .onDelete(perform: self.removeTipo2)
                         }
                     } // List
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide more details on goal in description. Any own tries?

Comment: Yes, edit it. I am testing with two listings, each depending on the segment selected. But it does not refresh when changing the selected option

Comment: Your change `self.$userData.tipoSeleccionado` in Picker but view depends on `self.containedViewType`, are they joined? Show us these both types declarations.

Comment: Not really. I realized that it only worked when I was running the ActionSheet that causes the containedViewType to take the type I want